# Get line number (count of newlines) when piping in bash

Tags: bash, jq

I am converting a file of json documents to a file of differently shaped json documents using jq. I need the output documents to have a contiguous positive id. Can I access a variable that equals the number of newlines seen?

```
gzcat input.gz | jq -r '"{\"id\":???, \"foo\":\(.foo)}"' > output
# can anything take the place of ??? to give 0..n?
```

Comment: Are you actually streaming in the `jq` sense? Your example doesn't seem to be.

Comment: No. Streaming in the bash piping sense. Have updated the question title.

Comment: You could try adding line numbers by piping through `cat -n`. If it needs to be in JSON format for jq, try `sed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your jq has `input_line_number`, you might be able to use that.  Here is a typescript illustrating what it does:

```
$ jq 'input_line_number'
"a"
1
"b"
2
```

(In the above, the input line is immediately followed by the output line.)

Similarly, here is how `foreach` and `inputs` can be used together:

```
$ jq -n 'foreach inputs as $line (0; .+1; "line \(.) is \($line)")'
"abc"
"line 1 is abc"
123
"line 2 is 123"
```

If your jq does not have `foreach`, then you might find `reduce` adequate for your needs:

```
$ jq -s -r 'reduce .[] as $line
    ( [0,""]; .[0]+=1 | .[1] += "line \(.[0]) is \($line)\n")
    | .[1]'
```

Input:

```
"abc"
123
```

Output:

```
line 1 is abc
line 2 is 123
```

Comment: Very promising. Please help me with a tad more: `gzcat data/part-00001.gz | head -3 | jq -n 'foreach inputs as $line (0; .+1; "line \(.id) is \($line)")'` errors: `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "id"`.  It is treating the input as a string, not a document, perhaps?

Comment: If you use `foreach` and `inputs`, it would be best to read up on them.  Also, not knowing what the output of gzcat is, it's hard to point you in the right direction: where does .id come from?  Did you perhaps mean: `line \(.) is \($line|.id)` ?

Comment: Ah, that's a great use of `foreach`.  It's a lot more useful than I realized. I thought it was literally a clone of `reduce`, but with an additional `extract` part.  I didn't realize that extract part was applied for every input, I thought it was only applied once at the end.